# Do we want to participate in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion

The year is drawing to a close and Stack Exchange is planning another Winter Bash. We, as a community, get to decide if we'd like to participate in this event.

For those who haven't seen one before, every year Stack Exchange puts on Winter Bash.  It's a period of a little under a month during which you get various hats for different activities around the site, similar to badges.  You can then display your choice of hat on your gravitar.  Some hats it is known how you get them.  Other hats are a mystery that it isn't obvious how you get it.

This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

We have until December 1 to decide. If we do not make a decision by then, we are opt'd IN by default.

Does Sound Design.SE want to gather hats this winter?

Comment: Do we just start seeing references to it over all SE from tomorrow? I haven't seen any advance info on it, other than a couple of metas saying 'shall we participate?'

Answer (score 7):

Don't be a hater... be a hatter!  Bring on the Hats!!!

Comment: Why not - bit of fun. First time I've heard of it as I'm new this year.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation as to what this is would be most appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: It's a fun, meaningless additional way to add flair to your user. You'll get various hats for various things, kind of like badges.  The hat will be 'worn' by your avatar for the duration of the program.  You can choose which hat to wear.  Some are more difficult to get than others. Others still, are more like easter eggs. Afterwards, they all go away as if nothing happened.

Comment: In all honesty, it's kind of a no brainer.  I guess there are some SE sites that don't want to be distracted? so they allow sites to opt out if they'd like.

Comment: Some of our academic sites would rather not have the additional noise, we understand and respect that. Users can also opt-out as they see fit, if they're on a site that has hats and they just can't stand it. These people also eat kittens.